# Firebase Database Search Query

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to search my database using a string, such as "A". I was just watching this Firebase tutorial [Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database - The Firebase Database For SQL Developers #4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&t=629s) and it explains that, in order to search the database for a string (in a certain location), you must use:

```
firebase.database().ref.child("child_name_here")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "child_name_here")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "value_here_uppercase")
    .queryEnding(atValue: "value_here_uppercase\\uf8ff")
```

You must use two `\\` in the ending value as an escape character in order to get one `\`.

When I try this with my Firebase database, it does not work. Here is my database:

```
{
    "Schools": {
        "randomUID": {
            "location" : "anyTown, anyState",
            "name" : "anyName"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
databaseReference.child("Schools")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
    .queryStarting(atValue: "A")
    .queryEnding(atValue: "A\\uf8ff") ...
```

When I go to print the snapshot from Firebase, I get  back.

If I get rid of the ending `.queryEnding(atValue: "A\\uf8ff")`, the database returns all of the schools in the `Schools` node.

**How can I search the Firebase database using a String?**

Comment: Firebase Database queries are case-sensitive. In your sample JSON there is no school name starting with `A`, only a school name starting with `a` (lowercase).

Comment: You may know this, but for clarity, that technique will only search for strings *starting* with the character 'A' and not any substrings. Firebase cannot search for substrings directly so other self-made methods must be used.

Answer (score 0):

`queryStarting()` and `queryEnding()` can be used for number. For example: you can get objects with someField varying from 3 to 10.

for searching string: you can search whole string using `queryEqualToValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

This shows all customers that match `Wick`. (It's not swift but may give you an idea)

```
// sample
let query = 'Wick' 
clientsRef.orderByChild('name')
.startAt(query)
.endAt(query + '\uf8ff')
.once('value', (snapshot) => {
     ....        
})
```