# How to get records from Firebase that have names that start with a certain string?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

How would you query Firebase to return children with names starting with a particular string?

I am trying to use Firebase with this [autocomplete textfield project](https://github.com/mnbayan/AutocompleteTextfieldSwift).

They use NSURLSession to fetch words that start with the letters that are being typed into the textfield:

```
private func handleTextFieldInterfaces(){
 autocompleteTextfield.onTextChange = {[weak self] text in
  self?.fetchAutocomplete(text)
 }
}

private func fetchAutocomplete(keyword:String) {
 dataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
 if let data = data{
  do{
   let predictions = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
   var locations = [String]()
   for dict in predictions as! [NSDictionary]{
    locations.append(dict["description"] as! String)
   }
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.autocompleteTextfield.autoCompleteStrings = locations
   })
 })
 dataTask?.resume()
}
```

How could I do this with Firebase?

I think it's possible to use the isEqual to query exact matches but is there a starts with query?

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/locations")
exactLocations = ref.isEqual(keyword)
```

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/mnbayan/AutocompleteTextfieldSwift) the project you are referring to?

Comment: Yes thanks. Fixed my link. In their example code they use nsurlsession to get data from google places. I want to use my own Firebase data.

Answer (score 4):

You can query for strings starting with a specific substring with `queryStartingAtValue` and `queryEndingAtValue`.

```
ref.queryStarting(atValue: "value")
   .queryEnding(atValue: "value\\uf8ff")
```

See the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data).

Also recommended:

- [Firebase Database Search Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070244/firebase-database-search-query)
- [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Comment: Aha, I was missing the .queryEnding part which limits it to the value. Thanks!